# Pytest and database cleanup before running tests

Tags: python, python-3.x, testing, integration-testing, pytest

i am using Flask to build a web service and pytest for testing

i am using pytest fixtures to set up and tear down the test resources but i need to test a POST endpoint that will create some records in the database

How do we clean up these records ?

Comment: Don't know about flask but if you are interested, use [restfulpy][https://github.com/Carrene/restfulpy] framework instead, it is easy to use and also super easy to write tests. If you have questions about it, I will be happy to help you.

Answer (score 8):

You can [use a fixture to do that cleanup](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/fixture.html#fixture-finalization-executing-teardown-code).

```
@pytest.fixture
def cleanup():
    yield
    # This is executed when the test using the fixture is done
    db_cleanup()

def test_records_created(cleanup):     # pylint: disable=redefined-outer-name,unused-argument
    response = app.test_client().post('/path', json=payload)
    assert response.status_code == 200
    assert ...
```