# Using pytest with a dockerized Postgres database

Tags: python, postgresql, docker, testing, pytest

I'm currently creating a separate database for the sake of my tests. Is there any better solution to run the test suite when the database is running in Docker and I don't want my tests to mess up my production database?

Comment: I think "better" is too broad, can you elaborate more on the exact problem you have?

Comment: @hoefling for my project, I had to create a new database, do the migration using alembic and then I could run my test. this was on my local machine. but for my CI/CD pipeline have no idea how to do the test stage without this manual procedure. so I'm looking for a 'better' solution to avoid that. what I mean by that is what should I do instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are already using a dockerized database as your "production database". You could add a second dockerized database as a "develop database". This second instance should replicate the production database, and be spun up / torn down as part of the test suite.

**Advantages of using dockerized database instances as part of the test environment**

1. Ensures that the development environment mimics production
2. Allows to test database migrations before deploying to a production environment
3. Allows to test queries before running them in production
4. Once setup, maintenance can be easier than the maintenance of mocked data interfaces

**Advantages of mocking database connections in the test environment**

1. Initial setup is easier
2. Smaller project stack (e.g. Docker potentially not required)

Generally speaking, I personally go for the second approach just for small projects, and spend the time to set up a proper dockerized local environment for any medium or large project.

---

On a different note, to the additional question in comments of the OP:

> for my CI/CD pipeline have no idea how to do the test stage without this [create a new database and running a migration] manual procedure

Generally speaking, a suggested approach would be to:

1. Bundle any required dockerized interface in a `docker-compose.yml`
2. Create an entrypoint (this can be a Python function) that creates a database, runs database migrations and loads mock data to the database
3. Run tests

The exact commands on CI could look something like:

```
- docker-compose up  # Initialize database instance
- make dev-environment  # Call a Makefile recipe to create the database, run migrations and load mock data
- make tests  # Call a Makefile recipe to run the test suite
```

Comment: thank you for the thorough instruction. according to what you said, having a separate database for the test suite, isn't bad or unacceptable, right?

Comment: Not at all, I'd say it's recommended and standard practice. Here are some related resources [[1](https://adam-gligor.github.io/2021/08/30/docker-compose-pytest/)], [[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53625556/pytest-and-database-cleanup-before-running-tests)], [[3](https://dev.to/koladev/setup-a-testing-environment-with-docker-and-pytest-django-postresql-schema-issue-2ffo)]